# Issue with checkbox and textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a little issue with my code not displaying correctly. Right now if there's text in the textbox and I select something from the checkbox list, what I selected from the checkboxlist overrides what's in the textbox. I want to keep what's in the textbox and just keep adding on what's selected.

For example: Honda's in the textbox ... I select Dodge and Mazda I want to show
Honda, Dodge, Mazda

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim strText As String = ""

    For i = 0 To cbCars.Items.Count - 1
        If cbCars.Items(i).Selected Then
            If strText = "" Or strTeethText = Nothing Then
                strText += cbTeeth.Items(i).Text 
            Else
                strText += ", " & cbCars.Items(i).Text
            End If
        End If
    Next
    txtCars.Text = strText.ToString()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: is the code above in the click handler for cbCars?

Comment: Why call ToString() on a string?

Comment: Prefer String.Empty to "". It makes the code at least cleaner

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
txtCars.Text += strText;
```

or

```
txtCars.AppendText(strText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Dim strText As String = ""
```

to

```
Dim strText As String = txtCars.Text
```

You forgot to initialize your string to the value of the textbox, which is why the textbox was getting overwritten on your click handler.